Turning line segments into flange bolts?
I find myself making various models (furniture and related things) that involve fasteners. Because these are representational (i.e. intended to serve as plans for making things in the real world, not as end products in and of themselves), I don't need a lot of quality, but it would be very helpful to have a way of representing things like screws and bolts.
Now... I could use instances and make a model of every possible fastener, but this seems like a problem that would be better addressed with parametric modelling, i.e. using geometry nodes. Besides allowing things like diameter to be entered as inputs rather than being directly modeled, this would have the additional benefit of allowing me to use line segments (curves) to represent fasteners of different lengths without having to make a separate object for each length.
Let's focus on flange bolts as these seem the most complicated, and the hard fiddly-bits are likely going to be the same for most fasteners. Fortunately, because I don't need very high visual quality (and because the threads are often hidden anyway), I don't need threads. All I want is to turn the curve segments into pipes, representing the shafts, and to add simple heads consisting of a thin cylinder and a thicker hexagonal prism. (In particular, the heads need to stick to one end of each curve segment and be oriented according to the direction of the segment. Note that the head should be "beyond" the curve point, i.e. the curve segment corresponds to the shaft without the head.)
How can I accomplish this?

Here is a crude visualization of what I want as the end result. (This is poorly/unrealistically proportioned because I was just whipping up something as fast as possible. Geometry nodes would of course allow all of the dimensions to be easily tweaked.)


Check out the built-in addon Bolt Factory. I think everything you need can be found there most likely.

@Jakemoyo, unless I am missing something, that is exactly opposite what I want to do. Yes, I can use BF to create a highly detailed model of an exact bolt. However, it's impossible (okay, very difficult) to modify that bolt, and particularly it doesn't turn line segments into ("good enough") bolts using geometry nodes that also let me dynamically.

Okay, I confess, this was mainly an exercise in transferring knowledge to myself, but I also hope someone else finds it useful.
TL;DR
This is what I came up with after some refinements:


And here is a preview:

(If this was in edit mode, you'd see curve endpoints at the start and end of each of the shafts. Changing the bolt positions and lengths is just a matter of changing the line segments of the curve object. Head dimensions are inputs to the geometry nodes. Curved bolts are possible but discouraged. )
Explanation
The parts of the head are pretty simple; they're just Cylinders that use inputs for some of the parameters. (The flange also has a node to smooth the normals, since we don't want it to look faceted.) The slightly-tricky part is translating them so that when we use them as instances, the instance origin is the base of the head rather than the middle. (This also means the flange is aligned to the base of the head rather than having the hexagonal part sticking out both sides of the flange.) This is accomplished with a Vector Math node that multiplies the height of each cylinder by the vector {0, 0, -0.5}.
A cheeky Math node multiplies the input shaft diameter by 0.5 to get a radius. The other inputs could do this also, but I didn't bother. (This could also be skipped, but bolt shaft sizes are usually expressed as diameter rather than radius, which makes giving a diameter as input slightly more intuitive.) Turning the line segments into shafts is a simple matter of turning the computed radius into a circle and sweeping the curve with that using a Curve to Mesh node.
A Switch node allows the flange (which could also represent a washer) to be toggled on or off. This takes either the joined pieces of the head, or just the hexagonal bit,  and defines the instance geometry.
The final slightly-tricky bit is getting the heads to appear in the right places. I couldn't find a "correct" way to extract just the start nodes of each segment, so I use Curve to Points to get a set of points along each segment spaced a very large distance apart. (Practically speaking, since no segment will exceed this distance, this achieves the goal of obtaining only the first point.) The points' tangent needs to be folded, spindled and mutilated into the proper form to be used to orient the instances, which is accomplished with an Angle Euler to Vector node. This all is then fed into an Instance on Points to produce the individual heads, before finally combining everything with a Join Geometry node.
Obviously, the "make a flanged bolt head" and "instance on curve starts" bits are independent; the latter could be used to add any geometry to the start points of a set of curves.
